# Is getting money from advertisements like Google Ads considered a commercial usage?

Tags: internet, advertisements

Suppose I write an article on a blog that has Google Ads installed. Then, I use an illustrated image with a non-commercial use only license. I make money from advertising in my blog, not selling my articles. Am I breaking the license?

Comment: Do you mean specifically a CC-NC licence?

Comment: Yes CC BY-NC license

Comment: Is your use "primarily intended for or directed toward commercial advantage or monetary compensation"?

Comment: Are *you* the recipient of the revenue generated by Google ads?

Answer (score 2):

### This is commercial usage

Your blog generates advertising revenues just like every other **commercial** media organisation.

Comment: A hobby doesn't become commercial just because it generates some revenue. For example, if he has no reasonable expectation that his advertising revenue will exceed his hosting costs over the next three years, his use would almost certainly be non-commercial.

Answer (score 2):

The [license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc/2.0/legalcode) says, "You may not exercise any of the rights granted to You in Section 3 above in any manner that is **primarily intended** for or directed toward commercial advantage or private monetary compensation."

Do you write for the blog as a business and not a hobby? Do you consistently make a profit (or at least reasonably expect to make a profit in the next few years)? Are you self-employed working on the blog?

If the answers to questions like these is "yes", then your use is commercial. If the answers are "no", then your use is non-commercial.

Comment: OP, note the "primarily intended" in the license as quoted in this answer.